# How do I limit my own screen time as an adult?

Tags: windows-10, time

I have recently had this problem with Civilization, where it's 1 am and I'm still playing "one more turn".

Is there anything I can do to limit my screen on time?

What makes it more complicated is that I am an adult and it's my own computer.

I was thinking maybe something that will force me to solve a puzzle to continue playing or something like that.

Comment: Is it an online game? Some routers have "parental controls". If your router has that feature (or if you are wiling to buy a new one with the feature) you can configure it to shut off your Internet access at midnight. If the game does not require Internet access to function, you can set something up to stream music -- Pandora or the like -- via something like an Amazon Echo. Get in the habit of only playing the game when you can hear music. When the music stops, go to bed.

Comment: It's an offline game, not sure if music will help. I mean I know that it's late.

Comment: Hmmm. Offline, so that idea isn't gonna do it. How about this: set up the parental controls anyway, and write a scheduled task that runs every five minutes. The task pings Google, and if the ping fails, the task kills the Civilization process. And puts a Deny ACL on the Civilization executable. And changes the password on the Administrator account, but tells you that the new password is the result of some long multiplication, with randomly chosen factors. "Multiply 17845 by 88234 -- that's your new admin password."

Comment: You'll have to be using a non-admin account for everyday use. (You should be doing that anyway. :-) ) And you'll have to put a Deny ACL on calc.exe, to force you to do the multiplication yourself. And, as long as you're using a scheduled task, you don't even need the parental controls on the router. The task can just use the clock to decide when to cut you off. This is getting pretty convoluted. But then again, if it were easy to stop playing at a reasonable hour, you wouldn't have asked the question, eh?